Clipping a graph with xmin in pgfplots generates a corrupted pdf
Consider the following MWE.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin = 0, ymin = 0]
    \addplot gnuplot[domain = -5:5] {x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The output is, as expected:

But when I open the file in scribus, I get this:

This is not what I expected.
My real case scenario is that the standalone pdf is then included in an other document (with \includegraphics). If the (invisible) line is within the boundary of the actual page, then it's fine. But if the line goes out of the boundaries, then some printers will say that the pdf is corrupted (this is my guess).
Any idea on how to solve the issue?
My engine is luaHBTeX and my distribution is an up to date TeXLive2024.

Do you have any evidence that printers will complain? Having clipped elements is very common.

In addition to what samcarter mentioned, this is basically how clipping works, Someehere it says, don't show stuff outside this box / path. Bu that does not mean that the data is not there. And some programmes then don't follow the clipping instructions.

Yes, I did some experiments and I came to the conclusion that some printers will complain as I described. I thought that the data were gone after clipping but this is not how this work: thank you for the explanations. But my question remains: is there a way to solve the issue and discard all the data outside the clipping area?

no there isn't. This is a vector graphic, so there aren't single pixels that you can erase (unless you convert that to a bitmap). And printers should not complain if there is stuff outside the mediabox.

Ok. I guess I'll have to rasterize my file as a workaround. Sam, Lars or Ulrike, could you please write an answer so I can accept it? Thank you all.

However, there could be a way to discard the data at pgfplots level (that is not only clipping)?

BTW you don't need such a technical example, \documentclass[border=1em,crop=true]{standalone} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture}   \clip (3,3) rectangle ++(5,5);   \draw[ultra thick,red] (0,0) rectangle ++(5,5); \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}  shows the same issue when the PDF is opened in scribus.

To add to what @UlrikeFischer said, you can have a curve (say, a spline) that exits and enters the clipped area several times. Re-drawing that curve to remove the external part is not a job that can be done trivially. I would say that the printers that complain are bugged. And Scribus (I do not know the program) should have a flag/option to respect clipping (which it knows, as shown by the red square).

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, ymin=0]
\addplot gnuplot[domain=0:5, samples=13] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



(+1) Well. The trick here is to change the minimum value in the domain. That will work in this simple case but not in a more general case.

You could ask about these “general cases”. In general it is bad to use compile time and file size for something that is not shown. I can not imagine a single case where it is wanted for more than a few points.
